# How to disable a button after X clicks?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, button

I'd like my code to show me the content of an array when I click on a button.

One click for `array[0]`, second for `array[1]` etc. I got it, but I don't know how to disable the button (or just stop the function) when my array has run out of content. I tried some simple `for` loop, but it didn't work.

```js
var writing = (function() {
  var myArray = ["one ", "two ", "three!"];
  var counter = -1;
  return function() {
    return myArray[counter += 1];
  }
})();

function buttonFunction() {
  document.getElementById('parag').innerHTML += writing();
}
```

```html
<button onclick='buttonFunction()'>Click</button>
<p id="parag">...</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
var counter = -1;

var writing = (function () {
      var myArray = ["one ","two ","three!"];
      return function(){return myArray[counter+=1];}
    })();

    function buttonFunction(self) {
    document.getElementById('parag').innerHTML += writing();
      if(counter == 2)
       self.disabled = true;
      }
```

```html
<button onclick='buttonFunction(this)'>Click</button>
    <p id="parag">...</p>
```

Variable `counter` must be global to know the current `count` of clicks.

Comment: Why not `this`? Just curious.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Not sure. If any kindly let me know. Very helpful for me and OP too.

Comment: I don't know, that's why I asked you... I asked why you have used `self` instead of `this`...

Comment: How can we use `this` without the context of `button`. So i passed the context of button `(this)` in function call itself and accessed it as `self`, just a variable name.

Comment: Ah!!! I didn't notice that and I thought `self` was a keyword. LoL. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my initial mistake.
Just check in your anonymous function returned by `writing()` method for `counter` reaching `myArray.length`. In that case, disable the button like this:

```
return function(){
  if(++counter < myArray.length)
    return myArray[counter];
  else
    return "";
}
```

or

```
return function(){
  if(++counter < myArray.length)
    return myArray[counter];
  self.disabled=true;
  return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which doesn't require keeping track of the index:

```
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<p id="parag">...</p>

<script>
    var myArray = ["one", "two", "three!"];

    var button = document.getElementById('btn');

    // If array is empty at the beginning, disable the button immediately
    if(myArray.length === 0) button.disabled = true;

    button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

      document.getElementById('parag').innerText += myArray.shift();
      if(myArray.length === 0) this.disabled = true;

    });

</script>
```

`myArray.shift()` removes the first element from the array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and then you check if the Array is empty and if so, you disable the button.

Btw. Don't use onClick directly on elements ([Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice))